# RLC circuit and equivalent load resistance of a transformer

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter, oscillator, damping-factor

I would like to know when there is no more energy into the RLC circuit with the transformer. (R in RLC circuit symbolized the resistance at the secondary). I tried to simplify this model by doing an equivalent circuit without a transformer.  Then It will be easier for me to do others calculs...

Here are the circuits :

[image]

For the circuit without transformer, the quality factor according to my calculs (which may be wrong) is the following :

$$Q = \frac{Rload2*\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{L}}$$

According to my calculs which may be wrong, the equivalent load resistance at the primary is equal to : 
$$Rload2 = \frac{Rload3*Np}{Ns}$$ where Np is the primary turn number and Ns is the secondary turn number.

So the equivalent quality factor Q of the circuit with the transformer is equal to : 
$$Q = \frac{Rload3*Np*\sqrt{C}}{Ns*\sqrt{L}}$$

Nevertheless when I adjust Rload2 in the circuit without transformer to have the same quality factor Q, it rings differently.  I could understand that the voltage/current waveform is different but I have some trouble to understand why the same energy at t=0 will take more/less time to be dissipated if Rload2 is really the equivalent resistance of the circuit Rload3 with the transformer

Here are the results :

[image]
[image]
So what is my mistake ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Impedance transformation

A transformer converts an impedance by using the turns ratio squared. Your formula just used the turns ratio (un-squared).

The reason is quite simple when you analyse 1 ohm on a secondary with 1 volt across it. This bit is easy; the current is 1 amp. Now, if the transformer primary had ten times the turns, the primary voltage would be of course 10 volts and the load current taken as seen on the primary side is 0.1 amps. Hence, 10 volts divided by 0.1 amps = 100 ohms. That's called the primary referred secondary load impedance.

A 1 ohm resistor is transformed to 100 ohms using a 10:1 transformer.

Apart from the above, it is unclear if L7 took account of the primary magnetization inductance as would be seen when you connected the transformer in parallel with L8. In other words I couldn't check this because your values are unclear.

### Q factor

If you want to check your Q formula, [this wiki page on RLC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Parallel_circuit) can help. If I read your circuit correctly (i.e. the charging resistor can be ignored when the switch operates), then your formula is correct.

Comment: Thank you my bad again ! Thank you for the page ! :D